# Find matching duplicates and color each a different color

Tags: vba, ms-word, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicates in a document and have the font of each unique match be a different color.

I've modified code I came across and it works for the first two unique duplicate matches then stops.

I'd like to find only unique 5-digit integers that are duplicate matches (<[0-9]]{5}).

```
Sub ColorDuplicates()
 
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCIxCellndex As Long
    Dim xCol As Collection
    Dim xCell As Range
    'Dim xChar As String
    Dim xCellPre As Range
    Dim I As Long

    Set xRg = ActiveDocument.Words.Last

    xCIndex = 5
    Set xCol = New Collection

    For Each xCell In ActiveDocument.Words

        On Error Resume Next
        xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text

        If Err.Number = 457 Then
            xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
            Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)

            If xCellPre.Font.ColorIndex = 1 Then xCellPre.Font.ColorIndex = xCIndex
                xCell.Font.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Font.ColorIndex

            End If
            On Error GoTo 0


    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[0-9]{5}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If InStr(StrFnd, .Text) = 0 Then
      StrFnd = StrFnd & "|" & .Text
      i = UBound(Split(StrFnd, "|"))
    Else
      For i = 1 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, "|")) - 1
        If Split(StrFnd, "|")(i) = .Text Then Exit For
      Next
    End If
    i = i Mod 15
    If i < 7 Then
      i = i + 1
    Else
      i = i + 2
    End If
    .HighlightColorIndex = i
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
```

The above code can handle up to 14 duplicated numbers, after which the colours are recycled. As coded, it highlights them, rather than changing the font colour. To do the latter, change:

```
.HighlightColorIndex = i
```

to:

```
.Font.ColorIndex = i
```

If you need more than 14 font colours, you'll need to provide some arrangement for specifying which of the available 16 million colours you want to use - via their RGB values. For highlighting, though, only 16 colours exist, including black & white - both of which I've excluded.

Comment: This is great! I'm going to see about getting additional colors in the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help on this!

I was able to solve this with help a slightly different way. Here is the code with 71 distinct colors for each set of duplicates.

```
Sub HighFive()
Const MaxColors = 56
' include a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, under Tools References
Dim Fives As Scripting.Dictionary, F As Variant
Dim Colors As Collection, C As Integer
    Set Fives = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Colors = New Collection
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 240, 255) 'cyan
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 160, 0) 'orange
    Colors.Add RGB(240, 0, 255) 'fuchsia
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 255, 0) 'lime
    Colors.Add RGB(192, 192, 192) 'silver
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 0, 255) 'blue
    Colors.Add RGB(1, 0, 103)
    Colors.Add RGB(213, 255, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 0, 86)
    Colors.Add RGB(158, 0, 142)
    Colors.Add RGB(14, 76, 161)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 229, 2)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 95, 57)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(149, 0, 58)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 147, 126)
    Colors.Add RGB(164, 36, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 21, 68)
    Colors.Add RGB(145, 208, 203)
    Colors.Add RGB(98, 14, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(107, 104, 130)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 0, 255)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 125, 181)
    Colors.Add RGB(106, 130, 108)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 174, 126)
    Colors.Add RGB(194, 140, 159)
    Colors.Add RGB(190, 153, 112)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 143, 156)
    Colors.Add RGB(95, 173, 78)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 0, 246)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 2, 157)
    Colors.Add RGB(104, 61, 59)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 116, 163)
    Colors.Add RGB(150, 138, 232)
    Colors.Add RGB(152, 255, 82)
    Colors.Add RGB(167, 87, 64)
    Colors.Add RGB(1, 255, 254)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 238, 232)
    Colors.Add RGB(254, 137, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(189, 198, 255)
    Colors.Add RGB(1, 208, 255)
    Colors.Add RGB(187, 136, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(117, 68, 177)
    Colors.Add RGB(165, 255, 210)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 166, 254)
    Colors.Add RGB(119, 77, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(122, 71, 130)
    Colors.Add RGB(38, 52, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 71, 84)
    Colors.Add RGB(67, 0, 44)
    Colors.Add RGB(181, 0, 255)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 177, 103)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 219, 102)
    Colors.Add RGB(144, 251, 146)
    Colors.Add RGB(126, 45, 210)
    Colors.Add RGB(189, 211, 147)
    Colors.Add RGB(229, 111, 254)
    Colors.Add RGB(222, 255, 116)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 255, 120)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 155, 255)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 100, 1)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 118, 255)
    Colors.Add RGB(133, 169, 0)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 185, 23)
    Colors.Add RGB(120, 130, 49)
    Colors.Add RGB(0, 255, 198)
    Colors.Add RGB(255, 110, 65)
    Colors.Add RGB(232, 94, 190)

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    ' take this out of you don't want to reset the colors
    ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Color = 0
    ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Bold = False

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<[0-9]{5}>"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True

    End With

    While Selection.Find.Execute
        ' believe it or not, if this entry is not already in the dictionary, it won't give an error
        ' it will add the entry and perform the operation, like a true friend
        Fives(Selection.Text) = Fives(Selection.Text) + 1
    Wend

    C = 1
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        With .Replacement
            .Text = ""
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = Colors(C)
        End With
    End With

    For Each F In Fives.Keys
        DoEvents
        If Fives(F) > 1 Then  ' not sure if you want only 5-digit numbers with at least one dup, if no, remove this
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = F
                .Replacement.Font.Color = Colors(C)
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
            C = C + 1
            If C > MaxColors Then C = 1
        End If
    Next F

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible approach would be to take the code from my previous answer and replace:

```
Dim StrFnd As String, i As Long
```

with:

```
Dim StrFnd As String, i As Long, s As Long, r As Long, g As Long, b As Long, c As Long
s = 56: c = s ^ (1 / 3)
```

and replace:

```
i = i Mod 15
If i < 7 Then
  i = i + 1
Else
  i = i + 2
End If
.Font.ColorIndex = i
```

with:

```
r = (i Mod c) * 256 / (c - 1)
g = (Int(i / c) Mod c) * 256 / (c - 1)
b = (Int(i / c ^ 2) Mod c) * 256 / (c - 1)
.Font.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
```

This way, simply changing the '56' in 's = 56' will allow you to pre-specify the maximum number of colours to use. The code will then auto-select those colours from the 16,777,216 available. Naturally, as you increase/decrease the 's' value, the automatically-chosen colour series will also vary.

For an idea of the colours you'll get with this approach, try the following in an new document:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim i As Long, s As Long, r As Long, g As Long, b As Long, c As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .Text = vbNullString
  s = 56: c = s ^ (1 / 3)
  For i = 1 To s
    r = (i Mod c) * 256 / (c - 1)
    g = (Int(i / c) Mod c) * 256 / (c - 1)
    b = (Int(i / c ^ 2) Mod c) * 256 / (c - 1)
    .InsertAfter vbTab & ChrW(&H2588)
    .Characters.Last.Previous.Font.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try